# How can I view the reference number of SOOrder that I already copy from Quotation in QT Type?

Tags: acumatica

I mean I copy SOOrder #SO001 from the Quotation #QT001. Anyways, I see the reference of Quotation that SOOrder copy from so I want the same result in Quotation. I created trigger when I inserted new SO and then update to QT. By Manually, insert one by one it works well. Yet it got message error when I save SO that already converted from quotation: 'Error #91: Another process has updated 'SOOrder' record. Your changes will be lost.'. For sure, I think I will miss any steps.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgg_SOOrder
ON dbo.SOOrder
FOR INSERT
AS

--Update QT record with SO record's order info
UPDATE  SOOrder
SET     OrigOrderType     =   'SO',       
        OrigOrderNbr      =   i.OrderNbr
FROM    SOOrder               so
JOIN    inserted              i
ON      so.OrderNbr       =   i.OrigOrderNbr
WHERE   so.OrderType      =   'QT'
AND     i.OrderType       =   'SO'
AND     so.CompanyID      =   2--Business logic constraint
AND     so.OrigOrderNbr   IS  NULL
AND     so.OrigOrderType  IS  NULL
```

Comment: Only you could check the created SO from its origin by checking in the Financial Setting Tab there's an Original Order Nbr. and Order Type. If you have inserted a reference number on Customer Order field, you may probably find it on Order Nbr lookup

Comment: You mean in SOOrder form (ScreenId=SO301000), it will show Orig.Order Nbr if type=SO because SOOrder is created after copy from Quotation. But if I want to know what RefNbr of SOOrder that created from Quotation, it no place to review.

Comment: Yes, because when copy Quote to SO it does not automatically save right? The only way you could do is inserting a reference id/nbr on Customer Order field on Quote so once copied you can trace the Sales Order created.

Comment: The step that I create SOOrder copy from Quotation:
1. I create Quotation and I didn't put the Customer Order because I don't know that sequence number in SOOrder.
2. then I copy order so it convert quotation with status completed. After I open the quotation that already converted and open order again to copy reference number from SOOrder. Yet it created new SOOrder for me. It's not a good choice to use customer order to put the SOOrder refnbr.

Comment: Okay, two options may work, either you first create the SO then encode the generated nbr to Customer Referenced, then create the QT (if this wont conflict or contradict the business workflow) or Add a field on SO screen by customizing it then thats were you input the your reference then customize the lookup that would the customized field.

Comment: I think by customizing project it should be the good choice, but maybe it has others way to do. Anyways, thanks your answer.

Comment: @xxxAcuGeekxxx, I already created trigger below:

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER tgg_SOOrder
ON dbo.SOOrder
FOR INSERT
AS

--Update QT record with S2O record's order info
UPDATE  SOOrder
SET     OrigOrderType     =   'SO',       
  OrigOrderNbr      =   i.OrderNbr
FROM    SOOrder               so
JOIN    inserted              i
ON      so.OrderNbr       =   i.OrigOrderNbr
WHERE   so.OrderType      =   'QT'
AND     i.OrderType       =   'SO'
AND     so.CompanyID      =   2--Business logic constraint
AND     so.OrigOrderNbr   IS  NULL
AND     so.OrigOrderType  IS  NULL

Comment: @xxxAcuGeekxxx, but acumatica error in processing when I save SO after I converted from QT. 'Error #91: Another process has updated 'SOOrder' record. Your changes will be lost.'.